# Matplotlib Legend in For Loop

Tags: pandas, for-loop, matplotlib

Im am trying to plot multiple lines with their corresponding legend:

```
regions = ['Wales', 'Scotland', 'London', 'East of England', 'East Midlands',
       'Yorkshire and The Humber', 'South East', 'South West',
       'West Midlands', 'North West', 'North East']

plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
plt.title('Number of Vehicles per Region')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Number of Vehicles')
plt.legend()

for i in regions:
    region = raw_miles_df.loc[i].sum(axis = 1).reset_index()

    region = region.rename(columns = {'count_date':'Year', 0: 'vehicles'})

    region['Year'] = region['Year'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
    region = region.groupby(['Year']).agg(vehicles = ('vehicles', lambda x: x.mean().round(2)))

    plt.plot(region)
    plt.legend(i)
```

the method i have is not working:

[image]

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-the-dataframe-with-to-clipboard/52413247#52413247)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `plt.legend` out of the loop and make it `plt.legend(regions)`. As you can see in the legend, it is treating the string 'North East', which is the last item in `regions`, as an iterable from which to draw the categories.

But you can make it easier on yourself by using `seaborn`

```
import seaborn as sns
# aggregate your data outside of the loop
# then call lineplot
aggdata = df.groupby(...)
sns.lineplot(x=x_column, y=y_column, hue=category_column, data=aggdata)
```